# Prime elements in a commutative ring with identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

Prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ are numbers where its only factors are 1 and itself.

Let *R* be a commutative ring with identity.

Definition of a prime element for commutative rings with identity: A nonzero nonunit *p* $\in$ *R* is called a prime element if whenever *p* $\vert$ *ab* in *R*, either *p* $\vert$ *a* or *p* $\vert$ *b*.

Does the same statement hold then, that an element *r* of *R* is prime if its only factors are 1 and itself? It seems to be true as if *p* = 7, 7 $\vert$ 1 or 7 $\vert$ 7.

Comment: Note that $-1$ and $-7$ are factors of $p=7$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ to. You should consider factors up to multiplication by a unit (and the units in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $1$ and $-1$). In general, rings can have some pretty complicated unit structure.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following definition:

> Let $R$ be a (unital) ring. An non-zero and non-unit element $x\in R$ is called irreducible if it is not the product  of two non-units.

In an integral domain (no zero divisors) $R$, every prime element is automatically irreducible. However, in general irreducible elements need not be prime.

In many rings (such as unique factorization domains) irreducible elements coincide with prime elements.

Comment: I understand that Primeness and Irreducibility are linked, but my question is for a commutative ring with identity *R*, are the prime elements where its only factors are 1 and itself?

Comment: The answer to that is automatically no, even in $\mathbb{Z}$. For example $7$ is divisible by $-1$ as well. You should relax that condition and you'll end up with the notion of an irreducible element. Then the answer is still no, there are examples of non-prime irreducible elements. For example, $2\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Note that this ring is unital and commutative, so this would then answer your question.